# Why does the following javascript throw a TypeError?

Tags: javascript

Executing

```
var q = document.querySelector;
q("div");
```

throws a `TypeError: Illegal Invocation` exception. Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because the querySelector method requires an instance of document to work on. you can call

```
q.call(document, "div")
```

Which says run the method, with this = document

To elaborate, the reason you are getting the error is because if you don't use the above syntax 'this' inside that function will refer to 'window'. The function must have some form of checking to ensure that 'this' is of type document.

Comment: you can also do `var q = document.querySelector.bind(document);`